# odd even in python using if else

Tags: python-3.x

Given an integer, , perform the following conditional actions:

If   n is odd, print Weird
If n  is even and in the inclusive range of 2 to 5, print Not Weird
If  is even and in the inclusive range of 6 to 20, print Weird
If n is even and greater than 20 , print Not Weird

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please see [how to ask homework questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions). "Implement this feature for me" is off-topic for this site. Try making an _honest attempt_, and then ask a _specific question_ about your algorithm or technique.

Answer (score 1):

For fun this can be done on one line.

```
n = int(input().strip())

print("Weird" if n % 2 != 0 or (n >= 6 and n <= 20) else "Not Weird")
```

Answer (score 0):

well this is a Hackerrank question but anyway.

```py
n = int(input().strip())

if n % 2 != 0:
    print("Weird")
else:
    if n >= 2 and n <= 5:
        print("Not Weird")
    elif n >= 6 and n <= 20:
        print("Weird")
    elif n > 20:
        print("Not Weird")
```

Comment: it's python2. the tag says he needs an answer for python3

Comment: sorry @Sevy i edited it

Answer (score 0):

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    n = int(input().strip())
    if n %2 == 0:
        if n >= 2 and n <= 5:
            print("Not Weird")
        elif n >= 6 and n <= 20:
            print("Weird")
        elif n > 20:
            print("Not Weird")
            
    else: print("Weird")
```

Hope it helps!